# How do I create 1 .NET Settings per instance of DLL

Tags: appsettings, application-settings, settings

My service is a DLL and it can be installed multiple times.  The DLL has its settings stored in Settings.settings.  Each instance of the DLL will have its own Settings.settings. Can this be done with Settings.settings, or do I have to create my own configuration scheme?  I want to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible. I don't have to necessarily have separate files, just a mechanism for allowing me to load the correct settings for the correct instance of the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you could use an app.config that will get installed in the same directory as your service: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dllappconfig.aspx